# Why does access to nested types affect member resolution in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Assume I have a simple structure...

```
struct A {
    std::vector<uint32_t> v;
};
```

And I want to find the size of the vector element type...

```
sizeof(A::v);                        // legal
sizeof(decltype(A().v)::value_type); // legal
sizeof(A::v::value_type)             // illegal
```

Error message...

> example.cpp:18:44: error: no member named 'v' in 'A'

Why does the third version fail? I don't understand how adding another layer of scope resolution causes the more broad scope resolution to fail. In fact, the second example seems equivalent to the failing example, but obviously the compiler disagrees.

This is a what-if/language question. I am not trying to solve a particular problem with vector sizes but rahter understand this oddity of the language.

**Update**

Here is another example from an answer below that seems to further my confusion...

```
sizeof(decltype(A::v)::value_type);  // legal
```

How is `decltype(A::v)::value_type` different from `A::v::value_type` in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can get a typename from a variable using the :: token. Ignore sizeof and ignore A::v. The following doesn't work:

```
A a; // A is some type with a public typedef for value_type in its declaration
A::value_type b; // ok
a::value_type c; // error
```

GCC 4.7.1 gives me this error:

```
x.cpp:9:1: error: 'a' does not name a type
```

sizeof makes this confusing only because it is a compile time construct that accepts both types and variables as its parameter.

Comment: The sizeof observation is interesting. But I still have a mystery, In my example, why does adding the `::value_type` cause `v` to not be found in `A`?

Comment: @AndrewWhite because the `::` operator causes the compiler to look for namespaces (either actual namespaces or compound types (structs/classes/unions)). there are no namespaces named `v` in `A`

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't the last one fail because you are accessing an instance in the last one whereas in the second one you get the class name from the decltype(). If you wrap the third one in a decltype it works

```
sizeof(decltype(A::v)::value_type);
```

Comment: Then why does the first one work? But you hit the highlight of my questions, why is `decltype(A::v)::value_type` different from `A::v::value_type`?

Comment: Is your question more why did c++ not make it work than why  are A::v and decltype(A::v) different

Comment: I guess both. I am trying to understand the subtle inconsistency that I perceive. How can `decltype(A::v)::value_type` be ok but `A::v::value_type` cause the compiler to report that `v` doesn't exist all of a sudden.

Comment: well you can use the decltype to make a new instance of a class, you cannot use A::v to create a new instance. int a;decltype(a) b;

Comment: @AndrewWhite Easy answer: because `v` is *not* a type, so you cannot apply the scope operator (`::`) to it, nothing to do with `sizeof` at this point. The actual point where there is a difference is between `sizeof(A::v)` and `sizeof(decltype(A().v))` and the actual question should be why the former works, even though `A::v` doesn't name a type. But that is just how `sizeof` works, it accepts both types and variable names.